# MS Graph create permssion for Sharepoint Site - POSTMAN OK / Powershell NG

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

According to [MSDoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fNgX.png), I am trying to use powershell to give a site permissoin. I've tried the same on Graph Explorer with a user with Sites.FullControl.All, I got 201 result. Also I am using the same config with POSTMAN, it's also 201 result.
[image]

However, when I use the following codesnip

```
# Define parameters
$ClientId = ""
$ClientSecret = ""
$TenantId = ""
$SiteId = ""
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
# Create body for the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $ClientId
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
    scope         = $Scope
}

# Make the POST request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TokenEndpoint -Method POST -Body $body
# Define the URL
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/permissions"

# Define the body content
$body = @{
    roles = @(
        "write"
    )
    grantedToIdentities = @(
        @{
            application = @{
                id = ""
                displayName = ""
            }
        }
    )
}
# Define headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($response.access_token)"
}

# Send POST request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

I got the following error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:41 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $header ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRe  
   quest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com  
   mands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

We do not have Powershell Graph SDK installed. Want a pure REST api call from powershell. Any suggestions? Thank you

```
  [1]: https://According%20to%20[Link][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&t
```

Comment: You must convert the body to json before posting this to Graph.

Comment: # Define the body content
$body = @{
    roles = @(
        "write"
    )
    grantedToIdentities = @(
        @{
            application = @{
                id = ""
                displayName = ""
            }
        }
    )
}  | ConvertTo-Json still having the same error code 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can directly use **Microsoft Graph PowerShell** commands to achieve your scenario.

I registered one application and granted <kbd>**Sites.FullControl.All**</kbd> permission of **Application** type with admin consent:

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script by connecting to Microsoft Graph using **client secret credentials** and got response like this:

```
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph

$ClientId = "appId"
$TenantId = "tenantId"
$siteId = "siteId"
$ClientSecret = "secret"
$ClientSecretPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ClientId, $ClientSecretPass

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Sites

$params = @{
    roles = @(
        "write"
    )
    grantedToIdentities = @(
        @{
            application = @{
                id = "appObjId"
                displayName = "appName"
            }
        }
    )
}

New-MgSitePermission -SiteId $siteId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below Graph API call to check the created permissions, I got **response** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/permissions
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To create permission using REST API calls, you can make use of below ***modified*** script where I passed body as Json and got **response** successfully:

```
# Define parameters
$ClientId = "appId"
$ClientSecret = "secret"
$TenantId = "tenantId"
$SiteId = "siteId"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Create body for the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $ClientId
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
    scope         = $Scope
}

# Make the POST request to get access token
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TokenEndpoint -Method POST -Body $body

# Define the URL
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$SiteId/permissions"

# Define the body content as JSON string
$jsonBody = @"
{
  "roles": ["write"],
  "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": "appObjId",
      "displayName": "appName"
    }
  }]
}
"@

# Define headers
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($response.access_token)"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Send POST request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody

$response  # This will output the response of the request
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This approach works. If I install the PowerShell Graph SDK on that device. Our scenario is that there is no PowerShell Graph SDK installed. We prefer to just call the REST API directly. There might be limitations with Invoke-RestMethod. I will mark this one as the answer for now.

Comment: Please check the updated answer where I added modified script to call REST API directly.

Comment: That really worked lika a charm. Thank you.